# Create sorted 2D array from 1D array

Tags: python, arrays

I want to turn a 1d array into a sorted 2d array. The 1d array looks like this:

```
[1,5,8,9,9,1,4,6,7,8,41,4,5,31,6,11]
```

First, I want to split this array up into a 2d array with a width of 4.

```
    [[1,5,8,9]
     [9,1,4,6]
     [7,8,41,4]
     [5,31,6,11]
    ]
```

Then, I want to sort the 2d array from the 3rd value in the 2d array like this:

```
    [[9,1,4,6],
     [5,31,6,11],
     [1,5,8,9],
     [7,8,41,4]
    ]
```

I am anticipating that the 1d array will be much larger, so I do not want to manually create the 2d array. How do I approach this?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use numpy, you can do it like this:

```
a = [1,5,8,9,9,1,4,6,7,8,41,4,5,31,6,11]
result = []
l = len(a)
for i in range(0, l, 4):
    result.append(a[i:i+4])

result = sorted(result, key = lambda a: a[2])
# result is [[9, 1, 4, 6], [5, 31, 6, 11], [1, 5, 8, 9], [7, 8, 41, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try numpy array_split

```
import numpy as np
a=[1,5,8,9,9,1,4,6,7,8,41,4,5,31,6,11]
b=np.array_split(arr, len(a)/4)
for c in b:
   c.sort()
```

Comment: Even after correcting the typo (arr/a), this doesn't provide the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If you use numpy.argsort, you can sort it easily.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1,5,8,9,9,1,4,6,7,8,41,4,5,31,6,11])
arr_2d = np.reshape(arr, (4,4))
sorted_arr = arr_2d[np.argsort(arr_2d[:, 2])]
```